GStreamer stream synchronised h.264 video and random data
I am designing a camera that produces H.264 video streamed over RTP. I now need to also stream raw data (just data, not video nor audio) alongside the video and be able to synchronise the video and raw data on the receiver.
The effect I'm looking for is the same as audio/video streaming, where both can be resynchronised frame by frame on the receiver.
My current thinking is to send a second RTP stream with raw video payload as I think I should be able to sync the two RTP streams on the receiver.
Before I dive-in I'd like to know if anyone has comments or suggestions on my approach above and if there is a better way to do this?
